# matlab cell array size much larger than actual data

Tags: matlab, cell-array

I recently discovered an strange behavour of MATLAB cell arrays that was not happening before.

If I create a cell array with

```
a=cell(1,4)
```

its size is 32 bytes.

If then I put something inside, e.g.

```
a{2}='abcd'
```

its size becomes 144 bytes. But if I remove this content by putting

```
a{2}=[]
```

the size becomes 132 bytes and so on. What is the problem?

Comment: The answer is interesting but I think it can not explain what is happenning in this case. I discovered the problem when I show the size of the files created when I save the cell to a mat file. One moth ago the files were about 20 K in size. Now with a similar amount of data (and the same program) the size is more than 100 Mb. In the middle I upgraded from Windows 8 to Windoes 10. Can the problem be there? If so is there a solution? Thank you

Answer (score 7):

Simply put, the Matlab cell array needs some internal data structures to keep track of what is stored within.

As it seems, Matlab allocates memory as needed, and thus extends the storage needed by the cell array as you insert data.

Removing the data doesn't mean that matlab can return the now unused memory to the OS or internal memory pool -- that might either be something that is impossible with the internal storage structure, or something that would be *unwise* with respect to performance, because cell arrays from which data is removed are (speaking over all use cases of cell arrays) be structures that get updated often, so that "prematurely" returning memory just to acquire it back again a few instructions later would be pretty CPU-intense.

*As a general note:* Matlab has pretty terrible storage approaches for nearly everything but matrices and sparse matrices (vectors of course being special cases of matrices). That's because it's not Matlab's job to be e.g. a string parser etc.

If memory becomes a problem, it might be worth considering implementing the math core of your problem in Matlab and doing the rest in other, more generally usable programming languages and somehow interfacing your Matlab code with that -- I haven't tried that myself, but Mathworks has a  [Matlab engine for python](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab-engine-for-python.html), and I'd take writing python for things like storing arbitrary data over using Matlab every day; with that engine, you can call Matlab to do your dirty math work, and use python to do your everyday scripting/programming work.

Notice that my bottom line here is that Matlab has great Math routines and impressive documentation, but if you want to actually *develop software*, using a general purpose tool/language is much more likely to be satisfying quickly.

I'd even go as far as saying that it's probably worth your time to learn python, just to be able to circumvent having to deal with things that Matlab wasn't designed for (and cell arrays are a prime example of what Matlab is really complicated about and what's extremely easy in python).

Comment: Very good answer. Too bad that a lot of people are intimidated by text spanning more than one paragraph;)

Comment: @AndrasDeak: hence, the first "TL;DR" paragraph ;)

Comment: @AndrasDeak: Nevertheless, I decided to structure my text into even more paragraphs for superior readability!

Comment: I noticed that, and I think it works great:) Even the original version was great with its increasing size of paragraphs. The moderately brave can read the first half;) (My original comment wasn't a piece of criticism, just an honest expression of sorrow;)

Comment: Also: your answer also explains why cells are terribly slow, and why they should be avoided whenever possible when working with large data.

Comment: @AndrasDeak: Thanks for the kind words :) I'd actually like to see the python/matlab engine in action -- there's so much legacy code in matlab waiting to be used in the real world :)

Comment: The answer is interesting but I think it can not explain what is hapenning in this case. I discovered the problem when I saw the size of the files created when I save the cell to a mat file. One month ago the files were about 20 K in size. Now with a similar amount of data (and the same program) the size is more than 100 Mb. In the middle I upgraded from Windows 8 to Windows 10. Can the problem be there? If so is there a solution? Thank you

Comment: @A.Maron The file size itself is often defined by the minimum block size, not the size of the contents.  Did you check both the "size" and "size on disk" values in the Properties window?

Answer (score 0):

You use

```
a{2}=[]
```

to 'kill' the data in that field. In reality you actually do access the data, that is you leave a non-empty cell entry with an empty double array. (Thanks to matlab for representing empty cells as empty doubles...)

but if you use (no curly braces, but parentheses):

```
a(2) = cell(1,1)
```

then the cell array size is back to "empty" = 32 bytes.